# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file on line 61

Tags: php, mysql

My code

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data

     // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM druglist") ;

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $response["DrugList"]= array();
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
            $DrugList = array();
            $product["Drugs Name"] = $result["Drugs Name"];
            $product["content"] = $result["content"];
            $product["Type"] = $result["Type"];
            $product["Company"] = $result["Company"];
             // success
        array_push($response["DrugList"],$DrugList);
    }
            $response["success"] = 1;
            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
         }else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
?>
```

Comment: in which file is this error? the one you're showing or another one that actually has 60+ lines of code

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are no 61 lines there...

Comment: Wow, what a question

Comment: maybe the issue is in db_connect.php which we can't see

Comment: Won't be in that file. Guess it comes from the include. Also, stop using `mysql_` - its deprecated and removed in PHP7. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO_*` drivers instead.

Comment: roses are red,violets are blue unexpected `}` on line 61

Comment: @KunalAwasthi You should ask the OP to add a new-line at the start of the file.

Comment: what new-line supposed to do ? @jeroen

Comment: @KunalAwasthi it would make the error on line 62 so your poem rhymes

Comment: i would suggest a edit with one more line @mast3rd3mon

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below codes:

$DrugList["Drugs Name"] = $result["Drugs Name"];
$DrugList["content"] = $result["content"];
$DrugList["Type"] = $result["Type"];
$DrugList["Company"] = $result["Company"];

instead of 

            $product["Drugs Name"] = $result["Drugs Name"];
            $product["content"] = $result["content"];
            $product["Type"] = $result["Type"];
            $product["Company"] = $result["Company"];
```

Comment: why should OP use this?

Comment: $product is never defined whereas $DrugList is

Comment: I guess this would solve one of the many problems the OP will still run into...

Comment: How will this solve unexpected end of file error?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile At least it fixes a problem in a file that we can actually see :-)

Comment: well for the fact they are assigning values to a non existent variable...